# List of fundamental data structures - what am I missing?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

I've been studying my fundamental data structures a bunch recently, trying to make sure I've got them down cold.

By "fundamental", I mean the real basic ones. Fancy ones like Red-Black Trees and Bloom Filters are clearly worth knowing, but they're usually either enhancements of fundamental ones (Red-Black Trees are binary search trees with special properties to keep them balanced) or they're only useful in very specific situations (Bloom Filters).

So far, I'm "fluent" in the following data structures:

- Arrays
- Linked Lists
- Stacks/Queues
- Binary Search Trees
- Heaps/Priority Queues
- Hash Tables

However, I feel like I'm missing something. Are there any fundamental ones that I'm forgetting about?

**EDIT: Added these after posting the question**

- Strings (suggested by catchmeifyoutry)
- Sets (suggested by Peter)
- Graphs (suggested by Nick D and aJ)
- B-Trees (Suggested by tloach)

  - I'm a little on-the-fence about whether these are too fancy or not, but I think they're different enough from the fundamental structures (and important enough) to be worth studying as fundamental.

Comment: heaps and prio queues could be classified as fancy :P

Comment: Probably anything beyond arrays and linked lists could be classified as fancy :P

Comment: 'fancyness' is almost certainly an analogue scale rather than a binary choice, if it can even be well defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science))

As a principle I never say try [anySearhEngine] on it, but you can checkout this list : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures

Comment: A Set is more a modelling construct than a fundamental data structure.

Comment: IMHO it is a very fundamental data structure

Comment: Oh wow. I did search for stuff like this (both on Wikipedia and Google), but somehow I didn't bump into this list. Thanks so much.

Comment: A set it totally a fundamental data structure.  It's not a list because elements cannot be repeated.  It's not a mapping, it's only the keys of a mapping.  It's very fundamental.

Comment: A set defines what it contains. I think as these definitions can be quite complex and because depend on arbitrary functions to define them, they should be considered too high level to be considered a fundamental data structure.

Comment: They do have implementations in lot of languages however

Comment: Yes, but data structures should be syntactic-sugar agnostic.

Comment: It is a mathematical concept, as syntactic agnostic as they come

Comment: often implemented as an iterface over a tree or hash table, but then you can argue that almost any structure is just some abstraction over arrays

Comment: @Vainstah : btw even boolean algebra is dependend on it, a set might very well be one of the most fundamental data structures around

Comment: I think a set is a datastructure in much the same way as queues and stacks are.  They're sort of "non-terminal" data structures.  They can be represented in many different ways, but they should all provide a consistent interface.

Answer (score 10):

Also the [Graph data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29) is fundamental.

Comment: Graphs are a mondelling construct and a data structure. +1

Comment: Awesome. I've been studying various graph algorithms, but I should refresh on the data structure itself.

Answer (score 6):

i think your question is unclear, because you're mixing implementation and purpose ...

the following types describe implementation:

- linked list
- double linked list
- [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)
- array
- [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)
- hash table
- (binary) tree
- "managed" (binary) trees (heaps, leveled trees etc., i.e. trees where insertion and deletion is not done directly but through a procedure that guarantees certain constraints for the tree)
- graph (although very fancy)

the following describe purpose:

- stack (means FILO & can be implemented by a linked list, but also with an array or vector)
- queue (means FIFO & can be implemented by a double linked list, or maybe in other sensible ways)
- dequeue (...)
- priority queue (means "Highest/Lowest Key First Out" this is an abstract concept, that can be implemented in [many different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503946/lookup-structure-for-handling-future-events-time-based))
- map/associative array/dictionary (means you map keys to values. often requires an extra function to convert keys into valid keys for the underlying hash table or tree)
- set (means, it's a collection, that is iterable and can tell, whether a value is an element of the set or not. every value, that is an element of the set must apear exactly once during iteration. a set may be mutable, or not (may allow to add or remove elements). routines for intersection, union, difference may be provided (e.g. as methods in OOP). when it comes to implementation, there's a number of possibilities)

well, there'd be one last thing I consider very much worth mentioning: [**algebraic data types**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) ... depending on the language, they either exist natively, or you have to emulate them ... [Haxe](http://haxe.org) and C# (as far as I've heard) would be two imperative languages offering them by simply allowing parameters for enums ... they can be used to implement lists, trees and many other nice things ... for example, they are perfect to represent [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s and a lot of other complex structures ...

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but they are still distinct data structures; you can be well-versed in linked lists, arrays, and other ways to implement stacks without understanding stacks themselves, and you can be well-versed in stacks without understanding their implementations.

I'm attempting to list the fundamental data structures, whether they're implementations or interfaces.

Comment: What an answer!

Answer (score 4):

B-Trees and other multi-trees

Comment: B-Trees are covered, are you implying fancy ones ?

Comment: Vainstah: B-Trees are different from Binary Search Trees. Good call tloach, it's been awhile since I've refreshed myself on those.

Comment: In that case they should be fancy according to his definition.

Comment: I think "fancy" and "fundamental" is a false dichtomy; B-Trees are both, since they are an absolutely essential component of pretty much any large database.

Comment: Also, they're interesting as an example for how a data structure can be optimized for performance under specific hardware constraints.

Answer (score 4):

strings, although they may be implemented as arrays under the hood (as are several other data structures).

Any program that interacts with the user will use strings.
It's important to know how to manipulate strings.

Comment: Variadic data types, lots of implementation cruft to be considered a fundamental data type.... but +1 as they are too important to ignore.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm a little on-the-fence about whether strings deserve separate consideration from arrays, but it can't hurt, especially since they're so important.

Answer (score 2):

> [Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)
>
> [Graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29)

Answer (score 2):

[Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)s, as the most simple kind of spatial index.

Comment: interesting and complex, but imo as it applies closely to 2-d space it is fundamental.

Comment: might I also suggest R-trees or QR-trees?  they're an interesting extension of quadtrees.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

Comment: ok, to clarify, the R-tree is more like an extension of a B-tree, and the QR-tree is a fusion of a quadtree and an R-tree

Comment: Those are very specific to GIS.

Comment: Not at all specific to GIS, useful anywhere you have 2-d data

Answer (score 2):

Cons cell. With that you can build several other data structures (lists, trees, etc.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons

Answer (score 1):

some may be considered less fundamental than others:

- mathematical vectors/matricies
- graphs, adjacency lists/matricies
- tries prefix/suffix trees
- spatial indexing - quad trees/ kd-trees r-trees
- streams/ sequences null terminated strings / big ints

Answer (score 1):

[Bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) is not fundamental but it is very handy and it can represented efficiently using integers (and bitwise operators)

Comment: +1 use them everyday- very easy and fast!

Answer (score 1):

Associative Array is the generic way of saying Dictionaries, Maps, etc.  You can find this in almost every framework.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Answer (score 1):

[Tuples](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Tuple).

Also, if I could nominate one not-basic data structure, it would be the persistent bit-partitioned prefix Hash Tries from Clojure. In general, I believe persistence to be a very important and often overlooked property of any data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot the basic ones: [struct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29), [object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29) and [enums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type).

Comment: These constructs are language specific and may be serialized ontop of fundamental types.

Comment: I consider these to be data types, not data structures. I imagine there are great arguments on both sides, but I also know these cold, so it's irrelevant for my purposes. Good call though :)

Comment: Structures are a kind of mapping from name to value.  While the C-language `struct` is language-specific.  The "record" (in COBOL or Pascal parlance) does exist in multiple languages.  This is the basis for "class" definitions.  So I would argue that it is not language specific, but exists almost everywhere.

Comment: I'm interested to hear about a programming language that does not support a struct-like construct!

Answer (score 0):

I would add maps unless you want to consider that to be under sets.

Answer (score 0):

[Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) since they serve as basis for modelling problems such as:

- Graphs
- Affine transformations
- Solving linear systems
- Markov chains
- etc

Comment: Not fundamental imo as they can be emulated using arrays.

Comment: what can't be emulated using arrays?

Comment: @jk everything can be, perhaps you should change the answer to be "sparse" matrices. These should not be emulated using arrays and I would think are fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

For help, read the Java Collections documentation.  They break things down into an abstract tier (Set, List and Map) and an implementation tier (ArraySet, HashSet, ArrayList, LinkedList, TreeMap, HashMap).

For help, read the Python Collections documentation.  They break things down into abstract base classes like Set, Sequence and Map which are built up from mixin features of a collection.

Comment: offtopic post, he is not asking about the names of programming manuals.

Comment: Sorry, but the reference material in these language references will answer the question.

Comment: Well most of those types exist to provide complexity guarantees, and as such are not fundamental. I doubt the manuals are going to be discussing the containers in a language neutral way either.

Comment: The "reading" part of the answer is central.  Read the descriptions. Learn what other people thing fundamental data structures are.

Comment: @S. Lott --I agree, hardly off-topic.  It's not like you're shilling for the publishers.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [union/find datastructures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).  They are fundamental to some graph algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

A "function object", "function pointer", or "closure" can't be implemented in certain restrictive languages that have arrays, linked lists, etc. But perhaps they are closer to data types rather than data structures.

The ["rope" implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) (as implemented in the "cord" library) is my favorite implementation of the "string" abstract data structure, but perhaps it's not really "fundamental".